# json data not parsed into

Tags: javascript, php, json, canvas

I try to fetch php data, retrieved from MySQL, json encoded into javascript file to draw a linechart.

My json data looks like

> php data.php

```
[
    {"x":"1","y":"925"},{"x":"2","y":"1000"},{"x":"3","y":"1000"},{"x":"4","y":"11"},{"x":"5","y":"52"},{"x":"6","y":"84"},{"x":"7","y":"109"},{"x":"8","y":"132"},{"x":"9","y":"270"},{"x":"10","y":"291"},{"x":"11","y":"306"},{"x":"12","y":"330"},{"x":"13","y":"356"},{"x":"14","y":"374"},{"x":"15","y":"395"},{"x":"16","y":"411"},
    ...
    {"x":"33","y":"887"},{"x":"34","y":"905"},{"x":"35","y":"921"},{"x":"36","y":"940"},{"x":"37","y":"1000"},{"x":"38","y":"1000"}
]
```

When try to parse this data into my js html and open the page in a browser it doesn't have any content:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="canvas/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
                title:{
                    text: "Documents"
                }
                {
                    data: [{dataPoints: result}]
            });
            chart.render();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Does anyone see what could be wrong here? or could give some hints how to troubleshoot this?
I was looking at chrome's developer tool, but that doesn't show any error. 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a comma here:

```
    text: "Documents"
}    // <-- There
{
    data: [{dataPoints: result}]
```

Replace that with:

```
    text: "Documents"
},   // <-- There
{
    data: [{dataPoints: result}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma at the end of your first object

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I removed the whole text: .. block, but still the browser keeps empty. Do you have any other suggestions?